# How to stop Jquery animation and speed it up

Tags: jquery

I tried coding a scroll function on mouse down, but it won't stop immediately when I release the mouse. The longer i hold the mouse down the longer it scrolls after i let go. It doesn't change the speed when I change the amount of pixels it should move. How can I fix that?

```
$(".body__overlay").on("mousedown", () => {
        scolling = true;
        startScrollingH($('html, body'), "20");
    }).on("mouseup", () => {
        $('html, body').stop();;
        scolling = false;
    });

function startScrollingH(obj: JQuery<HTMLElement>, spd: string) {
    if (scolling) {
        obj.animate({
                scrollTop: "+=2000px"
            },
            1000, "linear", function () {
                startScrollingH(obj, spd);
            });
    } else {
        obj.stop();
   }
```

Comment: What are you expecting here? That duration of 1/1000th of a second and repeatedly calling startScrollingH means it is being called hundreds of times a second.

Comment: I tried it with more delay but It didn't work either

Comment: What is expected? We can't help if you don't provide a proper explanation. [ask]